# Query Mysql não retorna erro nem resultado

Tags: mysql, join

Tenho 5 tabelas nas quais cada uma delas tem dados que preciso ser exibido agrupado por data. São propostas, agrupadas por data, quantidade de propostas, valor das propostas, mídia, valor investido, quantidade de cliques, código (source_code) e se é negada ou aceita.
o resultado seria mais ou menos esse:

```
data_proposta | source_code | custo(total por data) | midia | cliques | impressoes | custo | negadas | aceitas
```

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada proposta, outra mídia (que traz cliques, valor, impressões), precog (valida ou não) e source_code. 
Cada proposta é salva em uma nova linha da tabela propostas e essa consulta faz um `COUNT()` na quantidade de propostas, separar por propostas negadas e aceitas  com um `COUNT()` tbm.
Traz da tabela mídia a quantidade de cliques, valor do custo agrupado por data com base no `source_code`.

Estou tentando fazer um `select` no MySQL e o phpMyAdmin simplesmente não retorna erro nenhum e também não exibe o resultado.

Vejam minha *query*:

```
SELECT data_proposta, 
       propostas.source_code, 
       Sum(midias.custo)             AS custo, 
       Count(data_proposta)          AS propostas, 
       Sum(IF(precog_fk <> 9, 1, 0)) AS validas 
FROM   propostas 
       LEFT JOIN midias 
              ON `data_proposta` = `midias`.`data` 
GROUP  BY data_proposta 
LIMIT  0, 1
```

Comment: Ajudaria também colocar as estruturas das tabelas (ao menos os tipos dos campos que são usados na query).

Comment: Troque o `LEFT JOIN` por `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @Dorathoto já utilizei o outer join e nao aconteceu nada.

Comment: tipos dos campos:
data_proposta(datetime), source_code(varchar), custo(decimal(10,2)), precog_fk(int); É isso.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso abaixo:

```
SELECT a.data_proposta, 
       a.source_code, 
       Sum(b.custo)             AS custo, 
       Count(a.data_proposta)          AS propostas, 
       Sum(IF(precog_fk <> 9, 1, 0)) AS validas 
FROM   propostas a, midias b
       a.data_proposta(+) = b.data
GROUP  BY a.data_proposta
```

Comment: Isto te serviu? @DeBarros

Answer (score 0):

O problema pode estar no formato do campo da data, como você não passou a estrutura de tabelas, fica difícil identificar o problema, veja se isso resolveria o seu caso:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_proposta, '%d/%m/%Y') as data_proposta, 
       propostas.source_code, 
       Sum(midias.custo) AS custo, 
       Count(DATE_FORMAT(data_proposta, '%Y-%m-%d')) AS propostas, 
       Sum(IF(precog_fk <> 9, 1, 0)) AS validas 
FROM   propostas 
       LEFT JOIN midias 
              ON data_proposta = midias.data 
               where custo > 0
GROUP  BY data_proposta, propostas.source_code
```